# outline attribute conflict for IE and chrome

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, outline

I have a problem here, I have a checkbox and a hyperlink in the html:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>                                                              
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="readAndAgree" name="readAndAgree">
            <div>
                <label for="readAndAgree"> 
                    I have read and agree to the <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">Credit Profile Authorization</a>. 
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

When press "tab" you can see there's dotted border around checkbox and hyperlink.

But if add the css in the head,

```
 <style>
        input{outline-color:green;}
        a{outline-color:green;}
 </style>
```

the dotted border around the checkbox and the the hyperlink disappear in IE 8, 9 10.  IE7 still showing it.

I add the outline-color attribute for chrome to show the green outline when press "tab" instead of default orange color.

---

So how to compatible these two browsers? In chrome, it will show the green highlight, and at the same time, in IE 8, 9, 10, it will show the dotted outline/border when press "tab"?

In ie7 it will show because ie7 doesn't support outline. but IE8 with !DOCTYPE, IE9, IE10 support outline.

Comment: "So how to compatible these two browsers?" I don't get it. What is your question?

Comment: my question is :how to make it in chrome to show the green outline, and at the same time, in IE 8, 9, 10, to show the dotted outline/border when press "tab"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS:

```
  input:focus,
  a:focus {
    outline: 1px dotted;
    outline: auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
    outline-color: green;
  }
```

press tab and:
ie, ff, opera: show dotted border
chrome, safari ring border

http://jsfiddle.net/84bFN/3/

Comment: thanks for your answer, it works!! In addition if I want to remove the dotted outline when click it, but keep the dotted outline when focus it, how to implement that? I tried                          a:active, a:visited { 
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}   but it doesn't work.

Comment: a.special:focus:active,
a.special:focus:hover {
  outline: none;
} like this http://jsfiddle.net/84bFN/6/embedded/result/